# Permissions - Member Group Permissions overridden by Entry Access

Tags: members, member-management

In a complex website I have a Channel which a Member Group (Minutes) has got full access to.
I want the users of that channel to be able to add and edit those entries and those of other Authors in that Entry.
Those permissions are all set for the member group.

But the Entry Access plugin is also installed and the default permissions it adds to each entry if for the Administrators group.

But now if a member in the minutes group adds an entry to the channel, another member in that Minutes group can't edit that entry. under the Entry access Tab it only has the permissions set for the Administrators Group.

It is running ExpressionEngine 2.10.1 with the Structure Add on and Entry Access Add on.